# Jenkins build of Gradle project only succeeds when starting Gradle Docker container as root

Tags: docker, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-docker

I have a Jenkins running as a standalone server, i.e. it is *not running* as a Docker container. For building my application with Gradle I'm using a Docker image as shown below.

```
stages {
    stage('Compile') {
        steps {
            script {
                docker.image("gradle:6.2.2-jdk8").inside("-v ${HOME}/.gradle:/gradle/.gradle") {
                    sh './gradlew clean vaadinPrepareNode build -Pvaadin.productionMode'
                    sh "mkdir -p ${GRADLE_DEPENDENCY_PATH} && (cd build/dependency; jar -xf ../libs/*.jar)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

My problem is the following: There is a Gradle task which tries to access the directory `/.npm`. However the `jenkins` user launching the Docker container (`uid=1002(jenkins) gid=1002(jenkins)`) seems not to have the permissions to do that. Therefore the task fails.

When changing the pipeline statement to `docker.image("gradle:6.2.2-jdk8").inside("-u root -v ${HOME}/.gradle:/gradle` the build finishes successfully but then I have folders owned by `root` in the workspace which cannot be deleted by Jenkins.

Comment: What directories are mentioned by you which you cannot delete?

Comment: Just found out that it doesn't seem to be a problem. The build works fine and so does the cleanup by Jenkins. I was just wondering if it's recommended to run the container as `root`?

Comment: https://medium.com/@mccode/processes-in-containers-should-not-run-as-root-2feae3f0df3b